# input ref didnt work after adding react hook form option

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I try build file upload components with `react-hook-form`.  This is my FileUploader component:

```
import { Button } from 'antd'
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { AiOutlineUpload } from 'react-icons/ai'

const FileUploader = ({field, accepted="", id}) => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const handleClick = () => {
    if(inputRef.current) inputRef.current.click();
  };
  
    
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        ref={inputRef}
        className='hidden' 
        type="file" 
        accept={accepted}
        id={id}
        {...field}
      />
      <Button icon={<AiOutlineUpload />} onClick={handleClick} >Faýly saýla</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FileUploader
```

After I want to add react-hook-form option:

```
const {control, reset, register, formState: {errors} ,handleSubmit} = useForm()
    const onSubmit = (d)=>{
        console.log(d)
    }
return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='mt-3 px-5 m-6'>
              <Controller 
                    name="input"
                    control={control}
                    render={({field})=>(
                        <FileUploader 
                            field={field}
                            accepted='.txt'
                            id="input"
                        />
                    )}
                />
    {/* other fields */}
       </form>
)
```

After I click button file bar dont open. When I see console `inputRef.current` equal to null. How to fix it? I try do this wih `register` but dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spreading the React Hook Form field properties `{...field}` into the input element after passing your `ref` to it using `ref={inputRef}` overrides your custom `inputRef` with the `field.ref` property, causing it to become `null`.

To register your input element's `ref` with React Hook Form and your custom `ref`, you can use the `useImperativeHandle` React hook. This allows you to customize and share the usage of the `ref`.

There's [an example of this use-case](https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#Howtosharerefusage) in the "How to share `ref` usage" section of the React Hook Form docs FAQ.

```
import React from "react"

const FileUploader = ({ field: { ref, ...fieldProps } }) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null)

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => inputRef.current)

  return <input type="file" ref={inputRef} {...fieldProps} />
}
```